# Superslides Won't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery, and I've had a lot of trouble getting a full screen slideshow to work. I've tried downloading jquery 1.11.1. I've linked to 1.8, 1.9, and 1.11.1. The first image shows up with the numbers "123" on it, but it's not dynamic. The other two images aren't showing up.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/superslides.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
<style></style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="slides">//Slides container to control width
 <div class="slides-container">//suggested form by superslides.com
<img src="images/dsc_0844-8x12.jpg" alt="">
<img src="images/dsc_0785-8x12.jpg" alt="">
<img src="images/dsc_0720-8x12.jpg" alt=""> 
</div>
</div>
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//Additional superslides plug-ins 
<script src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/application.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

//Initialize slideshow
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#slides').superslides({
animation: 'fade'
});
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#slides').superslides({ animation: 'fade' }); });` maybe useful

Answer (score 0):

Your use of non-HTML comments is probably not helping, since you're essentially polluting the DOM with text nodes, and the slideshow script may not be resilient to that.

Comments in HTML look like this:

```
<!-- Initialise slideshow -->
```

not this:

```
// This is a JavaScript comment
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and still no luck. Any help is appreciated. I was able to get the responsiveslides.js working, but the slides weren't full screen. That's why I decided to try superslides. I don't see a difference between the two.

Comment: Ok. I got it working. "Animation:'fade' doesn't seem to work. Instead, I put: $(function(){ 
 $('#slides').superslides({ 
 hashchange: false,
        play: 2000
 }); 
});

Comment: Ok. I got it working. "Animation:'fade' doesn't seem to work. Instead, I put: $(function(){ 
 $('#slides').superslides({ 
 hashchange: false,
        play: 2000
 }); 
}); It worked, but I don't understand why. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author of the plugin. What does its documentation say?